# Cannot get property of undefined browser window

Tags: javascript, electron

When running electron 13.1.X and above I get the error - menuHandler.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBrowserWindow').

code from main.js

```
const { electron, app, Notification, ipcMain } = require('electron');
var Path = require('path');
var url = require('url');
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
```

The error occurs from menuHandler.js:8

```
const { remote } = require("electron");
const Window = remote.getBrowserWindow();
```

And so, I can't use the function:

```
$("#minimize").click(function() {
Window.minimize();
```

});

Here it throws an error passing the above message, meanwhile it works fine on older versions of electron. Please how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Remote was removed from the main electron package, you have to install `@electron/remote` on your project.

To use this new electron remote add this to your main file:

```js
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize();
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const window = new Browser window();
require("@electron/remote/main").enable(window.webContents);
```

On your renderer:

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('@electron/remote');
```

Readme of the new remote module: https://github.com/electron/remote#migrating-from-remote